# How to create an API to select functions with arguments

Tags: python, api

I am trying to build an API that will allow me to pick different methods of extraction and comparison. Each method has its own set of parameters. What would be the most pythonic and cleanest way to do something like this:

```
class ThisObject(object):
    def __init__(self, input_file, extraction_method, analyses_method):
        self.input_file = input_file

        extracted_info = extraction_method(input_file, **parameters1**)
        analyzed_info = analyses_method(extracted_info)


this_object = ThisObject(input_file='~/some_file',
                         extraction_method=extraction_method.get_first_name(**parameters**),
                         analyses_method=analyses_method.get_percent_matrix(**parameters**)
                         )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [arbitrary argument lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists).